# How do I assign a Canvas Width that is half of the Window Width in xaml?

Tags: c#, wpa

I have:

```
<Window x:Class="qq.MainWindow"
  ...
  Width="500"
  Height="300" 
>
...
<Canvas x:Name="gca" 
        Width="250"
        Height="150" />
```

This does not work

```
<Canvas x:Name="gca" 
        Width=Window.Width / 2
        Height="150" />
```

How do I assign the Canvas Width to equal half of the Window Width?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want to use `<Canvas>`? It has very limited use in WPF/XAML - I understand it's intended as a transition path for WinForms devs who are used to using absolute coordinates.

Comment: I would put the Canvas in a UniformGrid with two rows and two columns.

Comment: XAML does not support inline C#-style expressions in XAML binding expressions - which is one of the many hurdles you'll encounter with XAML - I don't understand why Microsoft has still never addressed the major ergonomic pain-points with XAML for 15 years.